# custom function with ifelse and two objects needs to read from correct column in a dynamic way R

Tags: r, function, object, if-statement, xts

How can I make sure the data of both columns in an object (Data)
 look in the corresponding columns of another object (B_u) in a dynamic way via a custom function?

See example below:

```
# example data
require(xts)
set.seed(3)    
A    <- matrix(runif(18, max=9), ncol=2)
Data <- xts(A, Sys.Date()-9:1)
names(Data) <- c("C1", "C2")
```

This generates:

```
                 C1       C2
2016-04-28 1.512374 5.678813
2016-04-29 7.267648 4.608143
2016-04-30 3.464481 4.545215
2016-05-01 2.949609 4.806318
2016-05-02 5.418906 5.015245
2016-05-03 5.439546 7.811275
2016-05-04 1.121701 7.467378
2016-05-05 2.651408 1.003042
2016-05-06 5.198489 6.333195
```

Of this data I make quantiles (bottom 20% en top 20%):

```
# make quantiles based on dataset
B_q  <- (apply(t(Data), 1, FUN=quantile, probs=c(0.2,0.8), na.rm=TRUE))
B_l  <- B_q[1,]
B_u  <- B_q[2,]
```

Which results in:

For B_l

```
  C1       C2
2.195794 4.582972
```

and B_u

```
      C1       C2 
5.427162 6.786868
```

Create the function:

```
# function to test whether data is bigger than the quantile
test_a <- function(x,l,u)
{
   for (i in 1:(nrow(x)))
   for (j in 1:(ncol(x)))

    b <- ifelse(x > u[j] , 1, 0)

  return(b)
}
```

Problem / question starts here when the function is called

```
# calling the function (dynamic)
# How can i make sure the data of both columns in Data
# look in the corresponding columns of B_u?

result_wrong <- test_a(Data, B_l, B_u)
```

results in:

```
           C1 C2
2016-04-28  0  0
2016-04-29  1  0
2016-04-30  0  0
2016-05-01  0  0
2016-05-02  0  0
2016-05-03  0  1
2016-05-04  0  1
2016-05-05  0  0
2016-05-06  0  0
```

Of which C1 for 2016-05-03 gives an incorrect result as it should be one. One can see this from the next result when I call the column explicitly

```
# calling the function with explicit columns)
# If I explicit the column to look into, it works. 
# However I have 100 columns of data so that won't work

result_correct <- test_a(Data[,1], B_l[1], B_u[1])

           C1
2016-04-28  0
2016-04-29  1
2016-04-30  0
2016-05-01  0
2016-05-02  0
2016-05-03  1
2016-05-04  0
2016-05-05  0
2016-05-06  0
```

So how to make sure that in the function the correct column with corresponding column of the quantiles (in this case B_u) is used?

Comment: In the function, you didn't use `l`, so why exactly is that an argument in `test_a`?

Comment: because actually in another test I look for data which are in between the 2 quantiles ( u & l) . I just tested with your suggestion  c <- ifelse((x[,names(l)] > l[col(x[, names (l)])]) +0 & 
                 (x[,names(u)] < u[col(x[, names (u)])]) + 0, 1, 0 )  and it gives good answer!

Comment: The code in the function gets pretty long though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear where the "B_l" should be used in the function as the OP didn't used in the custom function.  Other than that, if the column names of 'Data' is not in the same order as "B_u", we can make it in the same order by specifying the `names` of "B_u" as column index in "Data" i.e. `Data[, names(B_u)]`.  The next thing to correct would be to make the lengths of both "B_u" and "Data" the same.  We do that by replicating each column of "B_u" by the number of rows in "Data".  Here, we use `col` to get the column index of "Data" to do the replication.  As the lengths are now equal, we can just do `>` to get a logical matrix which we coerce to binary by summing with 0.

```
test_a <- function(x, l, u){
    (x[, names(u)] > u[col(x[, names(u)])]) + 0
  }
test_a(Data, B_l, B_u)  
#            C1 C2
#2016-04-28  0  0
#2016-04-29  1  0
#2016-04-30  0  0
#2016-05-01  0  0
#2016-05-02  0  0
#2016-05-03  1  1
#2016-05-04  0  1
#2016-05-05  0  0
#2016-05-06  0  0
```